# How to add annyang library in angular2?

Tags: angular, annyang

I need to add [annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) library in angular2. Can anyone please suggest me how to add using system.js and typescript? We have a angular 1 [service](https://github.com/levithomason/angular-annyang/blob/master/js/annyang-service.js).

I created a annyang service the code is

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
declare let annyang:any

@Injectable()
export class AnnyangService {
  start() {
    annyang.addCommands(this.commands);
    annyang.start({continuous: false });
  }

  commands = {};
}
```

Component code

```
import { Component,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import {EventsListComponent} from './events/events-list.components'
import {NavBarComponent} from './nav/navbar.component'
import {AnnyangService} from './common/annyang.service'
declare var annyang:any

@Component({
    selector: 'events-app',
    template: `
    <h3>{{iv}}</h3>    
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click) = "clickEvent()">click</button>

})
export class EventsAppComponent{
    iv:any

    nameArray:Array<string> = ["a","p","n"]
    constructor(private annyang:AnnyangService){

    }
    ngOnInit(){            
            this.iv="asdf"
            console.log(this.iv)
            this.annyang.commands = {
                '*val': (val)=>{
                    console.log("command start")
                    this.updateVar(val)
                }
            }
            this.annyang.start();
    }
    clickEvent = function(){
        let abc = this.nameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.nameArray.length)) + 0]
        this.updateVar(abc)
        console.log(abc)
    }
    updateVar = function(val){
        console.log(this.iv)
        this.iv = val
        console.log(this.iv)
    }        
}
```

on click of button I am able to change "iv" but using annyang not getting the updated value though using the same updateVar and it is reflecting in console also. Do I need any event method instead of ngOnInit? or the way I am calling the service is not proper?

Comment: Why do you have `declare var annyang` instead of `import annyang from 'annyang';`? I don't know what the specific error is caused by but this is broken.

Answer (score 5):

It is an AMD module so this should be straightforward. (Steps 4 and 5 are optional but recommended)

1. If you are using jspm, run

   ```
   jspm install npm:annyang
   ```

   and skip to step **3**

   Otherwise, if you are using npm, run

   ```
   npm install annyang --save
   ```
2. Add the following to **systemjs.config.js**

   ```
   SystemJS.config({
     map {
       // whatever is there now... 
       "annyang": "npm:annyang/dist/annyang.js"
     }
   });
   ```
3. Create a service in **annyang-service.ts**

   ```
   import annyang from 'annyang';
   import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

   @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
   export default class AnnyangService {
     start() {
       annyang.addCommands(this.commands);
       annyang.debug(true);
       annyang.start();
     }

     commands = {};
   }
   ```
4. Since it doesn't look like annyang has any typings files available at this time, we can start to stub one out by creating a declaration file named **extra-types/annyang.d.ts**

   ```
   export default annyang;

   declare const annyang: {
     addCommands: <T extends {}>(commands: T) => void,
     debug: (yn?: true) => void,
     start: () => void
   };
   ```
5. Create an entry in **tsconfig.json**

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       // whatever is there now... 
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "paths": {
         "annyang": [
           "extra-types/annyang"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am having less experience in angular 2 will integrate and let you know if facing any issue.

Comment: @user1162084 right on. Just keep in mind there is nothing angular specific here at all. In fact that class could be an AngularJS service or an Aurelia service just as easily as an Angular2/4 service. I saw that you used `$rootScope.$apply` in your AngularJS wrapper but wasn't sure why.

Comment: that service I found somewhere for angular 1. Don't know how to use that

Comment: sorry for late reply I made a angular 2 project which detect voice commands using annyang library here is the link https://tell-and-watch.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved using ngZone

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.annyang.commands = {
        '*val': (val)=> {
            console.log("command start");
            this.captureVoiceAndSearchVideos(val);
        }
    };
    this.annyang.start();

}

captureVoiceAndSearchVideos = function (val) {
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.searchText = val;
                .subscribe(data=> {
                    this.results = data;
                })
        });
    });
};
```

and it works for me.

Comment: Could use revision... the inner subscription isn't hooked into an observable.