# How to add annyang in Angular 4 using webpack

Tags: angular, annyang

I have the same problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442379/how-to-add-annyang-library-in-angular2). My case is a bit different because I'm using webpack, instead of System.js. The project is Angular 4 and created with the lastest version of angular cli.

How can I map the resource with webpack?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?